# nhibernate, 2 datasources

Tags: nhibernate

I have been reading about using nHibernate and multiple datasources and I get the multiple session factory piece and making multiple calls to the db.

I need to know if I can maintain the "has-a / has-many" relationships in the model if the data resides in different data sources.  Is there a way to cascade saves and such?

I apologize if this has been covered or if this is ridiculous, just starting to get up and going with this stuff and it would be alot easier if I weren't using a model first approach.

Comment: Everything that is not possible in sql, is not possible with NHibernate.

Comment: well, it seems like it would be a common scenario that would have a common solution by now.  I guess I am hoping nHibernate is just more than it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paco is right on, just can't do it.

Comment: actually NHibernate != SQL so you can do it. Id depends though on the complexity of the required task

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible to do what you want by accessing the table in data source B via DataSourceBName.Schema.TableName in a SQL query sent to data source A, then it is possible to do what you ask.

Simply add the name of data source B to your schema name in the NHibernate mapping file for that class (class name="ClassB" table="TableName" schema="DataSourceBName.SchemaName"), and configure NHibernate to connect to data source A.

Also, make sure that you have the correct permissions to access both data sources.